# Reference custom interpolator for View Animation in XML

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have successfully written a new interpolator for a view animation by implementing the `Interpolator` interface like this.

```
public class MyInterpolator implements Interpolator {
  public MyInterpolator() {}
  public float getInterpolation(float t) {
    return somefunction(t);
  }
}
```

I know that I can use this interpolator programmatically by creating an instance and passing it to the `setInterpolator` method of the `Animation` class.

But is there a way of using `MyInterpolator` in the XML resources for my animations?

Comment: no, custom interpolators cannot be set in xml

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same thing, I encounter that android give support to this.[Android Custom Interpolators](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)